# Hive on Spark is not working - Failed to create spark client

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am getting below error while executing hive query as spark engine.

```
Error:
    Failed to execute spark task, with exception org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException(Failed to create spark client.)'
    FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask

Hive Console:
    hive> set hive.execution.engine=spark;
    hive> set spark.master=spark://INBBRDSSVM15.example.com:7077;
    hive> set spark.executor.memory=2g;

    Hadoop - 2.7.0
    Hive - 1.2.1
    Spark - 1.6.1
```

Comment: No,I am having 2worker node and 1master node

Comment: no not yet..still working on the issue

Answer (score 1):

> The YARN Container Memory was smaller than the Spark Executor
>   requirement.  I set the YARN Container memory and maximum to be
>   greater than Spark Executor Memory + Overhead.  Check
>   'yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb' and/or
>   'yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb'.

[Please see Source here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Hive-on-Spark-CDH-5-7-Failed-to-create-spark-client/m-p/39845#M1595)